# What is the difference between applying batch norm in DNN vs. using just weights and bias?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

Batch Norm is a set of operations applied to each layers' input value. It has the advantage of speedup the learning of network and introducing noise in each layer.

The operation can be summarized as follow :

$$\mu = frac{1}{m} \sum{z^{(i)}}$$

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{m} \sum{(z^{(i)} - \mu)^2}$$

$$z^{(i)}_{norm} = \frac{z^{(i)} - \mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 + \epsilon}}$$

$$\tilde z^{(i)} = \gamma z^{(i)}_{norm} + \beta$$

The $\gamma, \beta$ are just scalar parameters that multiplied to the input value of each layer. Weights and bias at that layer does the same thing. What are the differences between them.

Is adding new learnable parameter $\gamma, \beta$ trying to achieve the same effect of doubling the hidden layer in neural network ?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience of reading latex source code, stackoverflow does not support LateX. The formulas are quite simple, so hopefully that does not cause much problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

batch norm is normalizing the input each mini batch, otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: could you expand on this?

Comment: I think you can do batch normalization on each layer's input (which is represented as z in the above formulas).